# How should I increase a value at a step of every five year and put the values into a list in Python?

Tags: python

I have a value, a = 10, it's time-based, now I want to increase it at a step of every five years, that is 5 years' later, it become a *= (1+0.01), then I want to put them into a list for later calculation, so I come up with the below code:

```
a = 10
c = []
for i in range(6):
    b =[a]*5
    c.append(b)
    a *= (1+0.01)
print(c)
```

This gives the output: 
[[10, 10, 10, 10, 10], [10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1], [10.201, 10.201, 10.201, 10.201, 10.201], [10.30301, 10.30301, 10.30301, 10.30301, 10.30301], [10.4060401, 10.4060401, 10.4060401, 10.4060401, 10.4060401], [10.510100501, 10.510100501, 10.510100501, 10.510100501, 10.510100501]]

The values are all right, they are what I want, but the thing is that this "c" now is a list of "lists". That is c[0] is also a list: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10].

The question is how should I do to keep the values in c just like that but without those lists in list.

Thanks a lot for anyone who could help!

Comment: If you do not want a list of lists but just one list, consider `c.extend(b)`

Comment: what a magic! ha, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a little bit of change

```
a = 10
c = []
for i in range(6):
    b = [a]*5            
    c.extend(b)
    a *= (1+0.01)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `extend` instead of `append`:

```
a = 10
c = []
for i in range(6):
    b =[a]*5
    c.extend(b)
    a *= (1+0.01)
print(c) #[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 10.201, 10.201, 10.201, 10.201, 10.201, 10.30301, 10.30301, 10.30301, 10.30301, 10.30301, 10.4060401, 10.4060401, 10.4060401, 10.4060401, 10.4060401, 10.510100501, 10.510100501, 10.510100501, 10.510100501, 10.510100501]
```

---

As you can see, `.extend()` *flattens* the parameter array, while `.append()` does not:

```
>>> c = []
>>> c.append([1, 2])
>>> c.append([3, 4])
>>> c
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> c = []
>>> c.extend([1, 2])
>>> c.extend([3, 4])
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of List Comprehension:

```
c = [elem for sublist in c for elem in sublist]
```

This will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what is actually want. Just see the results

```
a = 10
c = []
print(5%4)
for i in range(15):
  if i%5 == 0:
    val = i//5
    if val!=0:
        a = a*(val+0.01)
  c.append(a)

print(c)
```